# Use JSON as a Scripted Data Set in Birt

Tags: json, eclipse, classpath, reporting, birt

I'm trying birt to generate report from a JSON Data .

I followed this tutorial : http://blogs.actuate.com/use-json-as-a-scripted-data-set/

And i have done all steps but when i click on Data Set --> Edit --> Preview Results ; i got nothing .

I suspect that i didn't include correctly apache commons library, i added the jar in properties-->report design--> Class path is that correct ?

so i'm kind of at loss since when i don't get any error and results are not showing in the preview of the Data set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JARs files that are intended to be used in scripts should be located at:

*[eclipse root]/plugins/org.eclipse.birt.report.viewer_/birt/scriptlib*

Eclipse has to be restarted to take new scriptlib JARs into consideration. Another option would be to put a JAR in the resource path and declare it as a resource of the report:

*Outline view -> click report root -> Properties -> Resources -> Jar Files -> Add*

But i highly recommend the "scriptlib" folder approach. If you still face issues, then you should run the report in debug perspective to find out why scripts don't work. There is a short description of the javascript debugger [here](https://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/project/notable2.3.php).

Comment: I ll try your first approach , i have already tried the second one and it worked for me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In the dataset open() the line

```
fisTargetFile =newFileInputStream(newFile("C:/Users/kclark/Desktop/test.json"));
```

should be

```
fisTargetFile =new FileInputStream(new File("C:/Users/kclark/Desktop/test.json"));
```